# Availability of background transparency for jpeg images

Tags: ios, image, gimp

I need to edit a png image,by giving it border and drop shadow effect. But the final size of the edited image is too high to use for  a mobile app .I know that size of jpeg is less compared to that of png.So i convert that image to jpeg and tried to give drop shadow  and border effect.But that image is not having transparent background..Is their any other methods to accomplish this using jpeg?

Comment: Nope. JPEGs just don’t support a transparent background. Are you compressing the PNG as far as possible? Also, how big is the image, and what do you consider unsuitable?

Comment: By compressing you mean scaling isnt it?

Comment: Is their any other format that requires only less memory and supports transparency?

Comment: By unsuitable I mean,my original image size was around 800 kb and after scaling and then adding both effects, it get reduced to around 400 kb.But my problem is if there are 25 images in my app,around 15 MB is gone for images.I dont want that.

Comment: No, I meant compression. Since you’ve tagged this with GIMP — I assume you export with that slider at 9? And how big are these images in area? A certain size is to be expected…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, jpeg image wont support transparency.But you can change the white background coming along with jpeg image

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to try either [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) for losseless compression, or its lossy cousin, [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com).

ImageOptim tries a series of lossless algorithms to shrink a PNG and selects the smallest result of the bunch. It has taken 25% to 50%+ of quite a few of our images.

ImageAlpha, on the other hand, is lossy and can further crunch the image, with results more like JPEG but without losing Alpha.

You would also do well to disable PNG compression in Xcode as shown [here](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html), with additional details [here](http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/).

Answer (score 0):

What @minitech wanted to say is not about scaling, it's about **file compression**. jpg and png files usually have some data that could be removed from the file. There are some compression methods to reduce file size (note that is size in kbs, not in scale measurement). Jpg images can reduce file size by reducing image quality, too.

If you want another file type that accepts transparency, there are the gif format, which gives you a smaller file, but have some drawbacks, like a lack of alpha channel (variable transparency). Check this link for more details: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/png-gif

There are a couple of online file compressors. If you want to compress png files, you could try using http://tinypng.org/